# Running Wald Test in R with different names of data (logistic regression)

Tags: r

Everyone, im going to run logistic regression with [SAFETY](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6vrqf30hx9e68jf/safety.csv?dl=0) data.
Here is my code:

```
library(lmtest)

data <- read.csv("C:/Users/user/Desktop/SAFETY.csv",header=TRUE)(your directory)
data$Type<-factor(data$Type)
data$Size<-factor(data$Size)
data$Region<-factor(data$Region)
mylogit<- glm(Unsafe~Size+Weight+Region, data=data,family = "binomial")
waldtest(mylogit,test="Chisq")
```

then it is worked.

but if:

```
df <- read.csv("C:/Users/user/Desktop/SAFETY.csv",header=TRUE)
df$Type<-factor(df$Type)
df$Size<-factor(df$Size)
df$Region<-factor(df$Region)
mylogit<- glm(Unsafe~Size+Weight+Region, data=df,family = "binomial")
waldtest(mylogit,test="Chisq")
```

It shows:

> Error " 'data' argument is of the wrong type"

May i know how to solve it if i insist to use name of `df`??
 Thanks for helping.

Comment: In that package, `df` stands for degrees of freedom. That's why it's not working. It will work if you rename the data with `df1` or whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not reproduce this issue on R 3.2.2 and `lmtest` 0.9.34 (see `sessionInfo()` output at the end).

Using this code:

```
library(lmtest)
dfS = read.csv("Data/SAFETY.csv")
logitS = glm(Unsafe ~ factor(Size) + Weight + 
               Region, data = dfS, family = binomial())
summary(logitS)
waldtest(logitS, test = "Chisq")
```

I was able to produce:

```
> summary(logitS)

Call:
glm(formula = Unsafe ~ factor(Size) + Weight + Region, family = binomial(), 
    data = dfS)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.7970  -0.5866  -0.3119   0.7864   2.2018  

Coefficients:
                Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
(Intercept)       2.7285     1.3949   1.956  0.05046 . 
factor(Size)2    -2.0200     0.6246  -3.234  0.00122 **
factor(Size)3    -2.6785     0.8810  -3.040  0.00236 **
Weight           -0.6678     0.4589  -1.455  0.14559   
RegionN America  -0.3775     0.5624  -0.671  0.50203   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 119.249  on 95  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  84.004  on 91  degrees of freedom
AIC: 94.004

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5

> waldtest(logitS, test = "Chisq")
Wald test

Model 1: Unsafe ~ factor(Size) + Weight + Region
Model 2: Unsafe ~ 1
  Res.Df Df  Chisq Pr(>Chisq)    
1     91                         
2     95 -4 23.987  8.035e-05 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

My suggestion would be for you to restart your R session and reload all required packages. Do a `rm(list = ls())` if required (CAUTION: this will remove all objects from your workspace).

---

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] lmtest_0.9-34    zoo_1.7-12       tidyr_0.3.1      samplesize_0.2-2 ggplot2_1.0.1   
[6] lazyeval_0.1.10  RMySQL_0.10.7    DBI_0.3.1        dplyr_0.4.3     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.1      magrittr_1.5     MASS_7.3-43      munsell_0.4.2    colorspace_1.2-6
 [6] lattice_0.20-33  R6_2.1.1         stringr_1.0.0    plyr_1.8.3       tools_3.2.2     
[11] parallel_3.2.2   grid_3.2.2       gtable_0.1.2     assertthat_0.1   digest_0.6.8    
[16] reshape2_1.4.1   labeling_0.3     stringi_0.5-5    scales_0.3.0     proto_0.3-10
```